# Cannot log in to Ubuntu after changing /etc/fstab

Tags: login, login-screen, fstab

I was recently trying to change my `/home` directory to a new hard drive using [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving).

I got to the step where I have to change the `fstab` file and I think what I did was I set the location to `/home` instead of `/media/home`. Well now when I try to log into my computer, it brings me back to the log in page, but it doesn't say that my password was wrong, so I know that's not the problem.

I've been trying to do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> thing to edit the `fstab` file from the command line, but its a read-only file. I also tried changing the permissions of the file with `chmod`, but that doesn't work either.

What else can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try to edit with `sudo`:

`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

Comment: bless you dude, worked like a charm...

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to change `fstab` file after remounting root filesystem in read-write mode, using this command:

```
sudo mount -o remount, rw /
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit it using `sudo $EDITOR /etc/fstab`

Answer (score 0):

Try: `sudo vi /etc/fstab` and after editing press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get vi go to command mode and then `:wq!` to save and overwrite